# Why igraph plot warns that "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"?

Tags: r, igraph

I have a graph with many edges between two nodes. When I plot it, I get a warning I don't understand in this context.

This works fine:

```
library(igraph)
gg <- graph.empty(n=0, directed=TRUE)
gg <- gg + vertex("10501")
gg <- gg + edge("10501", "10501")
gg <- gg + edge("10501", "10501")
plot(gg)
```

But the same graph with one more edge gives a warning:

```
gg <- graph.empty(n=0, directed=TRUE)
gg <- gg + vertex("10501")
gg <- gg + edge("10501", "10501")
gg <- gg + edge("10501", "10501")
gg <- gg + edge("10501", "10501")
plot(gg)
```

I fail to see the reason. Why this warning?

Comment: Same warning each time the number of edges is an odd number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Searching the `igraph` package source for the line giving the warning, it seems that the culprit function is `autocurve.edges` in `plot.common.R`:

```
autocurve.edges <- function(graph, start=0.5) {
  cm <- count.multiple(graph)
  el <- apply(get.edgelist(graph, names=FALSE), 1, paste, collapse=":")
  ord <- order(el)
  res <- numeric(length(ord))

  p <- 1
  while (p <= length(res)) {
    m <- cm[ord[p]]
    idx <- p:(p+m-1)
    if (m==1) {
      r <- 0
    } else {
      r <- seq(-start, start, length=m)
    }
    res[ord[idx]] <- r
    p <- p + m
  }
  res
}
```

According to `?igraph.plotting` (and the package source) the `autocurve.edges` function is the called by default to determine how to curve edges:

> By default the vector specifying the curvatire is calculated via a call to the autocurve.edges function. This function makes sure that multiple edges are curved and are all visible. This parameter is ignored for loop edges.

From early in `igraph.plot`, we can see that this function is called, being passed the whole graph:

```
curved             <- params("edge", "curved")
if (is.function(curved)) { curved <- curved(graph) }
```

This is the source of the warnings on the problematic graph:

```
autocurve.edges(gg)
# [1] -0.5 -0.5  0.0
# Warning messages:
# 1: In res[ord[idx]] <- r :
#   number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
# 2: In res[ord[idx]] <- r :
#   number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

To delve into why we're seeing these issues, the very first thing this function does is call `count.multiple`, which returns the number of times each edge is repeated. In the offending graph:

```
count.multiple(gg)
# [1] 1.5 1.5 1.5
```

Instead of returning `c(3, 3, 3)` (since the looping edge is repeated 3 times), it's returning `c(1.5, 1.5, 1.5)`. Though I don't see any mention of this in `?count.multiple`, this is happening because the count of an edge is divided by 2 if it is a loop (aka an edge from a node to itself), due to the following line in `igraph_count_multiple` from the `structural_properties.c` file in the `igraph` package source:

```
/* for loop edges, divide the result by two */
if (to == from) VECTOR(*res)[i] /= 2;
```

The fact that the warnings are generated is due to a bug -- `autocurve.edges` was expecting to get `c(3, 3, 3)` but instead got `c(1.5, 1.5, 1.5)` from `count.multiple` due to the loop edges. I think `autocurve.edges` could actually be reimplemented in pure R using something like:

```
autocurve.edges <- function(graph, start=0.5) {
  el <- apply(get.edgelist(graph, names=FALSE), 1, paste, collapse=":")
  ave(rep(NA, length(el)), el, FUN=function(x) {
    if (length(x) == 1) {
      return(0)
    } else {
      return(seq(-start, start, length=length(x)))
    }
  })
}
```

Further, I think the documentation of `count.multiple` should be updated to mention its special handling of loop edges.

In the meantime, I think the solution in your case would be to manually specify your curvature parameter to avoid the warnings:

```
plot(gg, edge.curved=FALSE)
```

**Update:** Submitted as a pull request to the rigraph project and now merged into the dev branch of the R igraph project: https://github.com/igraph/rigraph/pull/80

Comment: This is a really good pedagogical example of how to track down the source of a warning and following up in general.